# HTML String to PDF file using python at Aws-Lambda

Tags: python, html, pdf, aws-lambda

I receive HTML string in response.data from an external source. Using that HTML-string I need to convert it into a pdf and send it to another external source as Base64 format. All these things need to be taken care within the aws lambda. How to do it ?

What possibly I can do is.

I make a Request to external Source1-> I get a response -> I extract HTML string from response.data -> I can write it to a file named Sample.html -> I can convert this Sample.pd -> Conver this file into Base64 -> Send it to external source2

But the issue is, at AWS lambda, isn't it infeasible to create file and make all these changes.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to use files to output the result of converting a file to PDF.
Normally, libraries have a way to output the content as a string of bytes.
Check the parameter `dest='S'`in output function of FPDF for example: https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/output/index.html

About the usage of files in AWS Lambda.
It's allowed to use ephimeral storage.
If you need the data to be more persistent you should use AWS S3.